# Load indicator Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, foreach

I have three forms:

1. Login form
2. Browse users form
3. User profile

And some classes:

1. User
2. Article
3. App

So, my forms are creating with reloaded constructor. One of them are:

```
public UserProfile(User user)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Show();
        pictureBox2.Load("https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/34535/screenshots/631316/loader_gif.gif");
        string aJSON = @client.DownloadString(App.HOST + "api/get_user_articles?e=" + App.EMAIL + "&p=" + App.PASSWORD + "&u=" + user.id.ToString());
        articles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Article>>(aJSON);
        listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var article in articles)
        {
            ListViewItem aView = new ListViewItem(article.theme);
            string aUrl = client.DownloadString(App.HOST + "api/get_article_image?a=" + article.id);
            if (!aUrl.StartsWith("https://"))
            {
              aUrl = App.HOST + "assets/fallback/default_article-f8a3a64f38bb9b0d777f6722ab64ca0c.png";
            }
            byte[] imageData = client.DownloadData(aUrl);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
            Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
            stream.Close();
            imageList1.Images.Add(img);
            aView.ImageIndex = i;
            listView1.Items.Add(aView);
            i++;

        }

    }
```

This code is loading images and articles from remote server. Thih is very long-term process. I need to create some lazy load effect beetween window show and window complete load. Before that I've tried to create `PictureBox` on top of the form and send it to bottom when finish loading. But it doesn't work, because forms is on sleep mode when downloading data. Please write some problem solutions! Thank you!

Comment: Look into `BackgroundWorker`. You will be able to remove all that processing from your constructor, making your application continue its loading normally.

Comment: What is "reloaded" constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loading of the pictures must be performed in another thread.

You can use BackgroundWorker, here's a tutorial: http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker